# setting two Object.date attributes with one variable causing me problems

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain class x which have **startdate** and **enddate** among its attributes.so in my service i used this code to set the two values
`

```
    def date = new Date()

    date.set(hourOfDay: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, year: 2012 , month: 0, date: 1)

    x.startDate = date

    date.set(hourOfDay: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, year: 12 , month: 11, date: 30)

    x.endDate = date`
```

but the problem is it's giving the same value(**month 1 year 2012**) to both attributes eventhough i assigned diffrent value to them.

i tried using a debugger to see why this is happening and at first it assigns the proper value to **startdate** but when  the value of date is changed it also changes the value of **startdate** (**at line 4**).  the possible solution(workaround) is creating two date variables but i cant seem to understand why this is happening. can some one tell me why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the solution. You need separate date variables.

When you assign the date to the startDate or endDate properties you're setting a reference to the date variable. By referencing the same date variable in both properties any changes to the date variable are reflected in both properties.